# Uncompressing main.cvd hex database

Tags: database, hex, compression

I recently downloaded clamav hex database file "main.cvd".In other post i saw i need to delete 512 bytes in text editor and change extension to tar.gz,but how do I delete specified number of bytes from that file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in a hex editor (like [Bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/), if you're using Linux, or [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), if you're using Windows) and delete the required bytes.

Answer (score 0):

On linux

```
dd if=main.cvd bs=512 skip=1 | tar zxvf -
```